# Java8: Reduce list of elements like sql group by

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, reduce, java-stream

After a `stream().filter().map()` on a List I have a data structure of type `List<List<Object>>` that looks like this:

```
[["1","a",20],
 ["1","b",10],
 ["2","a",10],
 ["2","b",30]]
```

What I want is to group by the value of the first element of the inner list, leave the middle element out and finally sum the last elements for each "group".

```
[["1", 30],
 ["2", 40]]
```

Sorry if this is obvious for some of you, but I have yet to find any example of how to achieve this. I assumed it could be done by **Stream.reduce(U identity, BiFunction accumulator, BinaryOperator combiner)** but so far I haven't succeeded. If someone could provide some example code for this, I believe it would be appreciated by many others too.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the concept of "reduce" when I thought that was the right method to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code may be of help:

```
List<List<Object>> originalList = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("1", "a", 20),
        Arrays.asList("1", "b", 10),
        Arrays.asList("2", "a", 10),
        Arrays.asList("2", "b", 30)
);

final Map<Object, Integer> collectedMap =
        originalList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        e -> e.get(0),
                        Collectors.summingInt(e -> (Integer) e.get(2))));

System.out.println(collectedMap);
```

The output is:

> {1=30, 2=40}

Basically, what the code does is to `group` by the first value in the sublist (`get(0)`). Then it sums the integers by the use of `summingInt`. However, it groups the entire thing in a `Map` - if some other collection is required the stream must be slightly changed.

E.g. to collect the whole thing as a `List`:

```
final List<List<Object>> collectedList =
    collectedMap.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collectedList);
```

Then, the output will be:

> [[1, 30], [2, 40]]

Comment: Thanks. I was locked into the .reduce() pattern, and was not aware of the possibilities with Collectors! However, I do need the final result to be a List, but I could of course do that in a separate operation if required.

Comment: @aweibell: I have added an example of how to collect it as a `List` as well.

Comment: Thanks. I did it with a .forEach on the resulting map. :)

Comment: Perhaps not as clean as the collect variant, as I manually instantiated and populated the Lists.

Comment: You could also use `Collectors.toMap()` like that: `originalList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.get(0), e -> (Integer) e.get(2), (a, b) -> a + b))`